# How to pass an array to a view as Contextual Filter

Tags: view, drupal-7, drupal-contextual-filters

I am new in Drupal. I am currently developing an e-commerce site using drupal 7. I want to know how can i pass an array of nid to `views_embed_view('view_name','display_name',contextual filter)` contextual filters. Here is my sample code-

```
foreach($result as $record)
    {
        $querystring .= "+";
        $querystring .= $record->nid;       
    }
    $querystring = ltrim($querystring, '+');
    views_embed_view('tours_listings', 'page_2',$querystring);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add accomplish this by:
Checking the

> Allow multiple values on the view contextual settings page.
>
> If selected, users can enter multiple values in the form of 1+2+3. Due
> to the number of JOINs it would require, AND will be treated as OR
> with this filter.

Then instead of code above:
`$recordIds = array();`
`foreach($result as $record)`
`{`
`$recordIds[] = $record->nid;`   
`}`
`$querystring = implode('+', $recordIds);`
`//Do not forget to print this out.`
`print views_embed_view('tours_listings', 'page_2', $querystring);`